# I am creating an andriod app but stuck on creating a layout

Tags: xml, android-studio, user-interface, layout, material-ui

[home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfM20.png)
[card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61axe.png)
https://www.figma.com/file/qTJ3JFiQJXA61RP5M7X33X/UIFresh-quiz-app-ui?type=design&node-id=0%3A1&mode=design&t=07jmS1hejheKTdqq-1
i am creating a quiz app made the backend now creating home page, while creating the category card section i am stuck that the img goes beneath the card pls help. here is progress till now, pls tell how can i create such cards see img

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:background="F2F2F2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:text="HI JHON"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lets Memorise Trigno"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="54dp"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:background="@drawable/avatar_bg"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="46dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:src="@drawable/avatar"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView2"
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.15">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/trophy"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:src="@drawable/trophy" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/_348"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="68dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
            android:text="3498"
            android:textColor="@color/Rank"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ranking"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="68dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="Ranking"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="175dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="#ACACAC" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="205dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:src="@drawable/coin" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/coin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="243dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
            android:text="79800"
            android:textColor="@color/Rank"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="243dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="Coins"
            android:textSize="12sp" />


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Choose Categories"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView2" />
    
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

just provide me with sample code. Thanks in advance